# Tizen: native service_app denies permission to send launch request?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I wish to send a call on Tizen5.5 wearable and the closest way I can reach is to open the dialer:

```
app_control_h request = 0;
app_control_create(&request);

app_control_set_operation(request, APP_CONTROL_OPERATION_CALL);
app_control_set_uri(request, "tel:0123456789");

error_code = app_control_send_launch_request(request, NULL, NULL);
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "app_control_send_launch_request: %d", error_code);

app_control_destroy(request);
```

However this always get me `-13` which is *PERMISSION_DENIED*. Am I not allowed to launch from service app?

Manifest contains:

```
<privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/call</privilege>
<privilege>http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch</privilege>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following API:
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/wearable/latest/group__CAPI__PRIVACY__PRIVILEGE__MANAGER__MODULE.html#ga3c2f09747f4db04d81b681c10935ee5f

The call privilege is a privacy privilege.
To obtain permission from Tizen security, calling the ppm_request_permission() is needed.

e.g. calls ppm_request_permission()

```
static void __ppm_request_response_cb(ppm_call_cause_e cause, ppm_request_result_e result, const char *privilege, void *user_data)
{
  dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "privilege: %s, result: %d", privilege, result);
}

static int __foo(void)
{
  int ret =  ppm_request_permission("http://tizen.org/privilege/call", ___ppm_request_response_cb, NULL);
  if (ret != PRIVACY_PRIVILEGE_MANAGER_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "ppm_request_permission() is failed. error: %d", ret);
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I do this from service app, or I must have a UI app?

Comment: To answer my comment: it's perfectly doable from within a service app too :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get "User Approval" for Privacy Privilege. Refer to this page, https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/security/privacy-related-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

Since Tizen 5.5, you should ask permission to user using [Privacy-related Permissions
API](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/security/privacy-related-permissions/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).